# Помогите пожалуйста с примером. Язык Python

Tags: python

Определить столбец матрицы `В`,  сумма модулей элементов которого максимальна, если `В = 3*А^2 - А -7*Е`, где `Е` - единичная матрица, `А` - матрица размерности *5х5*, элементы которой определяется по формуле:

```
А[i,j] = i - j, если i == j; 
А[i,j] = i - 2*j, если i != j.
```

Вывести на печать получившуюся матрицу, указанный столбец и его номер.

```
import numpy as np
MatrixA = 0
for i in range(1, 5):
   for j in range(1, 5):
    if i == j:
        MatrixA = [(i - j)]
    else:
        MatrixA = [(i - 2*j)]


MatrixE = np.matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])


MatrixB = 3*(MatrixA**2) - MatrixA - 7*MatrixE
print(MatrixB)
```

Программа не видит матрицу `А`, когда я заношу её в матрицу `В` . Однако когда я прошу программу напечатать её, она выводит данные в один столбик.

Comment: Язык PyCharm?..

Comment: Ой. Python я имел ввиду)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш код. И опишите что с ним не так.

Comment: 1) Вы пытаетесь создать матрицу `А` не 5х5, а 4х4. 2) В действительности создаёте список с одним элементом `[0]` (последний элемент предполагаемой матрицы). ==> `MatrixA = [[0 if i == j else i-2*j for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]`

Comment: а вы видите матрицу А? А то, может быть, это не программа ее не видит, а матрица не существует?..

Comment: GrAnd, большое спасибо!

Comment: Эникейщик. Матрицу она видет, когда я прошу вывести. Я так понимаю, что когда я пишу print, программа после каждого цикла выводит получившееся число, а если нет, то просто 0.